# Hyperlink button always open google.com

Tags: swift, url, button, hyperlink, action

I made an action to open a link but when i press it, it always open google.com (both simulator and real phone).
Is it just because it's launched from xcode or something else?
Here's the code

```
@IBAction func linkPremium(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:"http://www.apple.com") as! URL)
}


func createMenu() {
    let menuWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width/2
    let menuHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height


    let ee = UIButton (frame: CGRect(x:0,y:280, width: menuWidth,height: 60.0))
    ee.setTitle("Premium", for: .normal)
    ee.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

    ee.addTarget(self, action: #selector(linkPremium(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    menuView.addSubview(ee)
    view.addSubview(menuView)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createMenu()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when I run this line in my simulator

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:"http://www.apple.com") as! URL)
```

it opens apple.com

check your closeMenu function to see if you're making any changes there

Comment: my bad, i don't call the closeMenu method but the linkPremium method